# why request stop after a certain time in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, request

I have this code, its function is to send a request of the type Jetta, to bring the text from the request, the website links are read from a text file, the problem is after sending 300 or 500 requests, the script stops without showing any error, it just stops working ??

```
import requests

sites = open(r'site.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8").readlines()

l_site = []

for i in sites:
    l_site.append(i)


for x in len(l_site):
    result = requests.get(f'{site}', allow_redirects=True).text
    open('result.txt', 'a').write(f'{result}\n')
```

Comment: Did you step through it in a debugger to see exactly what's happening when it stops?

Comment: Your code should fail with a NameError before the first request.

Comment: And it's bad form to repeatedly open a file within a loop when you should open it once before the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this is what you want:

1. read from `site.txt`
2. if the http request is successful, append the response payload to `result.txt`
3. if the http request failed due to timeout for example, append the result with the url to another file

Here's a piece of code that runs. Note that if you would like to catch more types of errors, you can change the `except` part.

```py
import requests

URLS_FILE = 'site.txt'
RESULT_FILE = 'result.txt'
ERRORS_FILE = 'result-error.txt'

def handle_url(url: str, result_file, error_file): 
    try:
        # 10 seconds timeout, not download time, but time to get an HTTP response
        content = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, timeout=10)
        result_file.write(f'{content.text}\n')
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout as e:
        error_file.write(f'{url}: {e}\n')




with open(URLS_FILE, 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
    with open(RESULT_FILE, 'a') as rf:
        with open(ERRORS_FILE, 'a') as ef:
            for url in f.readlines():
                handle_url(url, rf, ef)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is more to your function than you've put in here because I don't see where the `site` variable is being created.

You could do something along these lines to get a better idea of where it's stopping.

```
import requests

sites = open(r'site.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8").readlines()

l_site = [s for s in sites]

with open('result.txt', 'a') as fb:

    for site in l_site:
        try:
            print(f"Processing {site}")
            result = requests.get(f'{site}', allow_redirects=True).text
            fb.write(f'{result}\n')
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
```